# Propagating products from database within a particular session

Tags: node.js, ejs, e-commerce, session-cookies

I am creating an e-commerce project and want an item to have its details from what is stored in a MySQL database. I am working with ejs for templating and NodeJS. For some reason, my terminal is throwing an error and I can't seem to get the page rendered. I have viewed several tutorials but it's not working. Most tutorials use the forEach() method to loop through all the products but I want to do it for a particular product. I would appreciate any help and explanation as to what is happening. Also have to add that I am using sessions to save cart activity for a particular session.

[image: Setup for sessions]
[image: This is where I try to select the items with the particular index I need from my database and route is so that it can be rendered and used in the single_product view.]
[image: Here I try to use ejs to propagate the front end with the data from my database.]